# Notify Android Users

Tags: java, android, google-api, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to add the functionality on my app such that when a user likes a photo by another user that picture owner gets a notification that their photo was liked.  I am wondering which Google/Android service would be best for this.  My plan right now is to:

1. Have user like photo --> notify Google servers
2. Google Servers -->
       send message to all users (behind the scenes without notifying any
       users)
3. Have the app decide which users it applies to --> notify that
       specific user

Is there any service that can do that?  Is [Google Cloud Messaging](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html) the ideal service for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is. Your own server will need to handle the logic to figure out to whom to send a push notification. Then you'll send this specific (or more than one) user id from your server to the google server.

Comment: is there any other similar service?  I would prefer it be an in app message rather than a push notification but I can make this work.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "in app message"? There are basically 3 possibilities how you can get data to your app: push notifications, polling or an open connection like websockets. For your use case GCM sounds definitely like the right solution.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need GCM to send notification to other clients